# how to import a js file as raw in ES6?

Tags: javascript

it is done something like this using require:

```
const SigninExampleSource = require('!!raw!../examples/Signin');
```

below is a screen shot trying to do it in ES6
[image]

how can i fix this?

Comment: What environment do you use `import` in? Webpack, Rollup, Node.js?

Comment: @Finesse i am using webpack in node env.

Comment: So try to google "how to import file as plain text in Webpack"

Comment: Where does it say the word raw in relation to import in this? https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-imports